Stream closed with status: Status{code=NOT_FOUND, description=The database (default) does not exist for project 206531905809
Stream closed with status: Status{code=NOT_FOUND, description=The database (default) does not exist for project 206531905809 Please visit https://console.cloud.google.com/datastore/setup?project=206531905809 to add a Cloud Datastore or Cloud Firestore database. , cause=null}
after adding firebase to flutter project but in firestore database id is (default) and
when i run program error throw that (default) database does not exist
i changed all packages ,
created new project after delete previous one
and all possibility has done

Please use flutterfire configure command to setup your firebase project. https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=android#available-plugins
